# msg.sender is not equal to owner

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix, ether

I am trying to write HealthCare contract by taking the reference from this [Link](https://github.com/purulalwani/bHealth/tree/master/contracts). Where Doctor can only update the details of the Patient when Patient sends the address.

File: Patient.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Patient {
    string public name = "";
    string public dateOfBirth;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;

    function () payable{
        balances[msg.sender] = 40;
    }

    function getContractAddress() public view returns(address) {
        return address(this);
    }

    // ############### Get Functions Begin ######################
    function getName() external view returns (string) {
        return name;  // First_Name Last_Name
    }

    function getDateOfBirth() external view returns (string) {
        return dateOfBirth; // YYYYMMDD
    }
}
```

File: Doctor.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;
import './Patient.sol';

contract Doctor{
    // the address of the owner (the patient)
    address public owner;
    string public name;
    string public dateOfBirth;
    string public patient_problem;

    modifier isOwnerPatient {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    // constructor that sets the owner to the address creating
    // this smart contract
    function Doctor() {
        owner =  msg.sender;
    }
    // allows physician to add an allergy
    function AddProblem(string _allergie) public isOwnerPatient {
        patient_problem =  _allergie;
    }
}
```

But when I am running the `function AddProblem()` of `Doctor contract`. It is not going inside the loop. It seems that the `owner != msg.sender`. I am using remix IDE and inputting Patient's contract Address into Doctors `At Address` input area.

Answer (score 3):

## Loading a previously created contract.

The `At Address` field in remix allows you to treat an address as a contract of a certain type.

In this case you're telling it that the `Patient` contract is a `Doctor`, which is not correct.

But you have another problem...

#### The doctor contract doesn't make sense.

A `Patient` should have a `Doctor` and/or a `Doctor` should have multiple `Patient`s.

Is it perhaps that the `Doctor` contract is misnamed?

#### Patient adding a Doctor

Regardless, the `Doctor` seems to want to treat it's creator as the patient address, which means that the `Patient` should have a method to create a `Doctor` contract somewhere inside it via for example:

```
address public myDoctor;
function createDoctor() public {
    myDoctor = new Doctor();
}
```

Then you could create a `Patient`, call the patient's `createDoctor` function.

Once you have called that, you can get the `Patient`'s `myDoctor` address, and in remix, select the `Doctor` contract in remix, input the address you got from `myDoctor` into the `Load contract from address` field and click `Add Address`.

This should then mean you have a `Patient` and a `Doctor` visible in Remix, but then you'll need a method inside the `Patient` to call the `AddProblem` method inside it's `myDoctor`, since this will only be callable by the `Patient` and not by you.

Comment: I did everything you said. But as I input `myDoctor` address into `Load contract from address field` and clicked Add `Address`. I think that `msg.sender` is the address of `Patient` contract; and `modifier isOwnerPatient` is returning `False` because of which I am not able to access `function AddProblem`. Note: I am accessing the `function AddProblem` from the Doctor contract itself from `Run` tab. Can you help me on how to access the `function AddProblem`.

Comment: As I mentioned, you can not access those functions as you are not the owner of the Doctor, the Patient is.

Comment: Is there any way by which I can use `modifier isOwnerPatient`  and then Doctor can use AddProblem function.

Comment: I am also trying to access the `function AddProblem` using `myDoctor`'s address (i.e. `myDoctor.call(bytes4(sha3("AddProblem(string)")), _allergie);` inside `createDoctor()` function; where `_allergie` is the `string`. But then also I am unsuccessful in getting `patient_problem` value. Note: I have removed `isOwnerPatient` from `function AddProblem` which is in `Doctor` contract when performing the above task.

Answer (score 0):

You’re not using `at` for the correct reason. That field is used to get a reference to an already deployed contract The `msg.sender` will be the address that initiates the call into a function (after the reference to a deployed contract is established).

It looks like you’re trying to create a `Patient` contract, get the contract address, then create a `Doctor` contract using the address you retrieved. This will not work. If you want `msg.sender` in `Doctor` to be the address of the `Patient` contract, you would need to have the `Doctor` contract created inside `Patient` (`new Doctor()`).

Comment: I followed the approach that @norganna told. Now I am also trying to access the function `AddProblem` using `myDoctor`'s address (i.e. `myDoctor.call(bytes4(sha3("AddProblem(string)")), _allergie);` inside `createDoctor()` function; where `_allergie` is the string. But then also I am unsuccessful in getting `patient_problem` value. Note: I have removed `isOwnerPatient` from function `AddProblem` which is in Doctor contract when performing the above task.